# Android custom animations

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

How to create animations in android studio. I know about all inbuilt animations. But I want to animate a logo or create a transformation icon or to create a progress bar animation.

Comment: just use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: https://youtu.be/Rx-Kh_eEJ4o

Comment: This kind of animations I m taking abt

Answer (score 0):

view [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292930/custom-animation-in-android)(extend Animation class.)